# How should I model this in EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, ef-code-first

My app is supposed to have Medics and Participants.

They are all supposed to be able to login to the Site.

So, right now what I have is this.

```
public class Participant:Person
{
      public string EmergencyContactNumber;
}

public class Medic:Person
{
   public string MedicHospitalId;
}

public abstract class Person
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string LastName;

   public string UserName; //this is the Membership Provider UserName to associate the MembershipUser to the Person thats logging into to the system.

}
```

The problem with this is that a Medic could eventually also be a Participant... and I dont want to have to create a new User for that..
How could I change my model to allow this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd redo it to be a 'has a' instead of an 'is a' relationship.  so instead of a medic being a person, it would be related to a person, like :

```
public class Medic
{
   public string MedicHospitalId;
   public Person Person;
}
```

there would then be a medic table with a fk relationship with the person table.  same thing for the participant. this would allow for a person to be both, and clean up the model a little i think.

if you wanted to get even more crazy with it, you could denormalize it into more of an eav table, but that's for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe roles will be good solution for you?